# Sobrecargar operador de comparación "<" en C++

Tags: c++, sobrecarga-de-operadores

no estoy pudiendo sobrecargar el operador "<" en C++

Fecha.cpp:

```
bool DtFecha::operator <(const Fecha& f){
    return this->anio < f->anio;
}
```

En Codeblocks me da error, me dice que la función necesita 2 argumentos:

```
C:\...Fecha.h|24|error: 'bool operator<(const Fecha&)' must take exactly two arguments|
```

, pero cuando pongo 2 argumentos, me dice que necesita un argumento.

```
C:\...Fecha.cpp|49|error: 'bool Fecha::operator<(const Fecha&, const Fecha&)' must take exactly one argument|
```

Esto es lo que hay en la clase (Fecha.hpp):

```
bool operator <(const Fecha& f);
```

¿Cómo se implementa este método? ¿donde está el error?

Comment: Si no pones exactamente cómo has declarado la función y cómo la estás implementando es complicado darte una respuesta. En la declaración no importa solo la línea que has puesto... sino también es necesario saber si esa declaración es la única que existe y si está (o no) dentro de alguna clase o espacio de nombres... y en ese caso también su visibilidad (`public`, `private, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás redactando un operador libre como si fuese un operador miembro.

---

Hay dos maneras de redactar un operador para un objeto:

```
struct Objeto {};
```

Como función libre:

```
bool operator <(const Objeto &a, const Objeto &b) { ... }
```

Como función miembro:

```
struct Objeto
{
    bool operator<(const Objeto &b) const { ... }
}
```

---

La función libre requiere dos parámetros, el objeto a la izquierda del operador y el objeto a la derecha del operador. La función miembro requiere un parámetro, que será el objeto a la derecha del operador porque el de la izquierda es `*this`.

En tu `Fecha.hpp` tienes el formato de función libre (requiere dos argumentos):

```
bool operator <(const Fecha& f);
```

Pero en `Fecha.cpp` usas el formato de función miembro (requiere un argumento) pero de una clase diferente (`DtFecha` contra `Fecha`):

```
bool DtFecha::operator <(const Fecha& f){ ... }
//   ~~~~~~~ <--- miembro de la clase DtFecha
```

Necesitas ordenar tu código, no vas a obtener mensajes de error coherentes si tu código no es coherente.